# Flash wmode transparent - click behind

Tags: html, flash

Here's the situation: two absolutely positioned layers, same position and dimensions. The top layer contains a Flash movie that spans the entire layer, embedded with `wmode="transparent"` The bottom layer contains a HTML link that is mostly visible.

In a strange turn-around of events, IE7 and IE8 render the page as expected: the Flash movie is visible and mouse-interactive; and the link below the movie is partially visible and mouse-interactive. In FF3.6 and Chrome 8, the link is visible but not clickable.

**Example**

http://www.powers1.net/flash-test/test2.html

**Code**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 1; width: 550px; height: 400px; overflow: hidden">
        <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</a></p>
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" width="550" height="400" id="test" align="middle">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="test.swf" /><param name="quality" value="high" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
    <embed src="test.swf" quality="high" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="550" height="400" name="test" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Question**

How can I get FF, Chrome and other browsers to emulate this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wmode=transparent and wmode=opaque are evil.  And here's why:

• It works sporatically between different browsers when it comes to how it renders it with content.  As you've observed, sometimes the stage will allow clicks to bleed through, sometimes not... sometimes you'll get a flicker in the flash when trying to layer html content over the flash... etc..

• It kills flash performance, and drags the users machine down with it (causing CPU usage to spike).. this is mostly due to the Flash player being forced to send its rendering directions through the browser instead of directly to the GPU... aaand it's not able to intelligently throttle down its FPS when hidden from view.

• Random, god-knows-where-they-came-from bugs that appear in Flash once you flip wmode over to one of those awful options... I've seen firsthand text rendering bugs, shape-drawing bugs, and externalInterface bugs that magically disappear once you remove the wmode parameter, or switch it over to one of the other friendlier values.

Have you considered creating a hybrid?  A type of solution where you have several swf movies - their x/y in the browser window controlled by HTML?  I guess you'd still have to use wmode=transparent to layer it over the rest of the page, but then at least you'd consistently get your ability to click through to content below...

Comment: Ended up re-implementing the idea without Flash - instead, used HTML, CSS and transparent PNGs.